# How can we Format the JSON Values into PHP Variables

Tags: php, javascript, json, jsonp

I would like to know, how can we re-format the JSON values into PHP Variables?

We are getting the URL from a JSON based script through the "JSONP" dataType.

```
http://localhost/kendo-prac/data/update.php?callback=jQuery17107827386485878378_1331380511887&models=%5B%7B%22ID%22%3A%2213%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22RODDER%22%7D%5D&_=1331380521156
```

I Would like to reformat this URL into this type.

```
<?php 
    $callback = "jQuery17107827386485878378_1331380511887" ;
    $Title = "RODDER" ;   // This values encoded in &models=%5B%7B%22ID%22%3A%2213%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22RODDER%22%7D%5D
    $ID = 13 ;   // This values encoded in &models=%5B%7B%22ID%22%3A%2213%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22RODDER%22%7D%5D
?>
```

Please provide me suitable help, how can we do this?

Comment: callback part is simple. the `%5B%7B%22ID%22%3A%2213%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22RODDER%22%7D%5D` part is URL encoded string. You can first decode it and then parse it to JOSN object to get Id and Title values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json  = $_GET['models'];
$data  = json_decode($json, true);
$Title = $data[0]['Title'];
$ID    = $data[0]['ID'];
```

Comment: would this work if the returned data is in JSON-P format? It seems that's what he'll be getting back.

Comment: If you decode that string, it's just: `[{"ID":"13","Title":"RODDER"}]`. No P in there.